# Determine version number of Alamofire programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire in my app and I would like to print the version number to the logs during app start. Is there a way to access the version number programatically?

Comment: Are you using Cocoapods or SPM?

Comment: @Sweeper Using SPM

Comment: Then I don't think there is a way. Alamofire does have a `version` constant declared in one of its files, but it's unfortunately not public.

Comment: You might be able to retrieve the version before the build, by adding a quick script that would look for the `Package.resolved` and add it "somewhere". The script for instance, could create (if needed) a ".swift" file and put it there and you might be able to read the version then programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire's version is part of its default `User-Agent` header, so if you're logging your network request, the version should be part of that already. I can see that it could be useful for it to be public so it can be part of custom logging or other headers, so I'll look into making it public.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Swift Package Manager, and as stated [in previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77663237/1801544) of [Jon Shier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272952/jon-shier), the version isn't available publicly. It's [there](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift) but accessible only inside the framework.

Until then (as stated Alamofire might make the version public in the future), this is a little work around steps. I haven't fully tested it, I just checked the decoding and the "string output", I didn't go up to the Build Phase part, but I'll give you the main directive that I think should make it work.

What you could do is have a little script during build phase that would read the Package.resolved and generate a file with all the version.
Add that file to your Target and that should be good.

[SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen), etc use this behavior to generate "safe" assets (with the help of stencil, etc.)

You need to find your `Package.resolved` first.
Mine is at `./MyProject.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved` since I use a Workspace. In case of only a PBXProjet, I'll let you find it.

You could use different languages for the script, but since we are Swift developer, I'll go with that.

### Main Code:

The code could be:

```
struct ResolvedPackage: Decodable {
    
    let packages: [Package]
    
    struct Package: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let state: State
        
        struct State: Decodable {
            let version: String
        }
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name = "identity"
            case state
        }
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case packages = "pins"
    }
}

do {
    let path = "pathOfThePackage.resolved"
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResolvedPackage.self, from: jsonData)
    
    var lines: [String] = []
    lines.append("//AutoGenerated Code\n")
    lines.append("#import Foundation\n")
    lines.append("struct SPMVersion {")
    decoded.packages.forEach {
        lines.append("\t static let \($0.name) = \"\($0.state.version)\"")
    }
    lines.append("}")

    let output = lines.joined(separator: "\n")
    print(output)
    try output.write(toFile: "PathOfTheNewSwiftFileYouWant.swift", atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
} catch {
    print("Error while retrieving Package.resolved content: \(error)")
}
```

Sample output:

```
//AutoGenerated Code

#import Foundation

struct SPMVersion {
     static let alamofire = "5.6.4"
     static let alamofireimage = "4.2.0"
}
```

### In use:

- Make that code a "Swift Script" (I'll let you dig into that: more or less add `#!/usr/bin/swift` & `#import Foundation`, at the start of a new .swift file, and make it executable with `chmod`).
- Execute the script in the build phases by adding a `New Script Phase` and call it there from "Bash code".
- Add PathOfTheNewSwiftFileYouWant.swift to your target.

### Going further:

Of course, this code is currently "quick and dirty", you might dig into it with parametering a few things:

- Path of the PackageResolved in Script Parameter
- Path of the Output Swift file in Script Parameter
- Use a more "cleaner Swift Code" output, using Stencil or I think [SwiftSyntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax.git).
- Grab other parameters from the Package.resolved if needed, or modify the decoding (I did it quick and didn't want to use custom `init(from decoder:)`).
- Parse also the CocoaPods/Carthage resolved files if needed to have all of your libs versions (but check before hand if they don't generate already a "user friendly" resume of the versions).

Note that Package.resolved doesn't seem to list the dependencies (on my last test), so you shouldn't be able to get theses versions.